# Having issues with Perl dependencies

Tags: perl, makefile

I've taken over a project written in Perl that has a few dependencies such as `Template::Toolkit`, `Image::ExifTool`, and `GD` to name a few.  Currently, these dependencies are built into a directory ("deps" folder) using the `--prefix` option in `make`.  In the main Perl script, I have something like the following to import the necessary modules:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);
use lib "lib";
use lib catdir(qw(deps lib perl5 site_perl));
```

`catdir` is used to stray away from certain system requirements (such as assuming '/' is the folder separator; if someone has another alternative, I'm open to suggestions!).  The "lib" folder contains my modules, and the "deps/lib/perl5/site_perl" folder is where my dependencies were installed on my original machine.

However, after building the dependencies on another machine, it seems the needed libraries have moved around to different folders.  I now need to use these statements for my script to run correctly:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);
use lib "lib";
use lib catdir(qw(deps lib perl 5.14.2));
use lib catdir(qw(deps share perl 5.14.2));
```

I was wondering if there was anyway specify the prefix directory ("deps") and have the `use lib` pragma recursively search through that directory for my dependencies.  Also, the users of this script do not have access to the Internet, so compiling my project as a CPAN module would be counterproductive.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: All systems supported by Perl use "/". `require Foo::Bar;` is literally `require 'Foo/Bar.pm';`.

Comment: Thanks! After further research, I see Perl handles the file separators on its own.  However, http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=print;node_id=110030;replies=1 tells me otherwise for MacOS 9.  That thread seems fairly outdated though...

Comment: No, Perl doesn't handles the file separators at all. That post is wrong. Windows fully supports "/" natively.

Comment: I think INSTALL_BASE is what I want (http://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html#INSTALL_BASE). I should be able to get the correct directory with INSTALL_BASE/lib/perl5/$Config{archname} right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [INSTALL_BASE for the Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE) and [--install_base for Build.PL](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild#INSTALL-PATHS) when installing modules.  They provide [stable install locations](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aCookbook#prefix-vs-install_base).  PREFIX and --prefix try to emulate how perl has its system libraries laid out and is more useful for making packages.

Also you'll want to run `rel2abs` over the path before feeding it to lib to give you an absolute path.  This will protect you in case your code `chdir`s and then tries to `require` a module.  Or you can use [lib::abs](https://metacpan.org/module/lib%3a%3aabs).

And ikegami is correct, it's unnecessary to make the file paths passed to lib portable.  Just pass them in Unix style.  Perl will figure it out.

Comment: Do I need to use both INSTALLARCHLIB and INSTALLPRIVLIB when importing my dependencies? As in:
`use Config;
use lib "deps/lib/perl5";
use lib "deps/lib/perl5/$Config{archname}";`

Comment: Nope, Perl should find the archlib for you.